# In Django, How Do I Move Images When A Dynamic Path Changes?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django app with an image field (a custom ThumbnailImageField type) that auto-generates the file path for an image based on the title, type, and country of the item the image is attached to (upload_ to = get_ image_path).  Here's how:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    dir = 'images'
    subdir = instance.get_type_display()
    sub_subdir = 'other'
    if instance.country:
        sub_subdir = instance.country.name
    name = instance.name
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]

    return "%s/%s/%s/%s.%s" % (dir, subdir, sub_subdir, name, extension)
```

It works great, except in one situation:  When I rename an item, change the country it's from, or change the category it's in, the image becomes a dead link because it generates a new image path without moving the orignal file.

So, the magic question:

Is there some save function in Django that I can hook into and override that will let me have the original object and the proposed values and compare them so I know where the image path was and where it will need to go (and then use this info to move/rename in code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look into signals:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

In particular, the django.db.models.signals.pre_save signal:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#pre_save

Comment: Agreed, but I would think the solution would be to use a post_save signal handler for the models that affect the path

Comment: Well, either way, that gets me the file move.  Updating the file path database field is a separate problem and not as important.  Thank you.